# How to set up this complicated grid of plots in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to achieve the following grid:

[image]

The four plots share their y-axes, and the bottom center duo share their x-axis. How do I achieve this in matplotlib?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `plt.GridSpec` (see doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html)):

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure()
gs=plt.GridSpec(12,16)
axs=[]
axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[0:6,0:4])) #Top left subplot. WIll be used as a reference to share y axis with the other 3 subplots on top
[axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[0:6,4*(i+1):4*(i+2)],sharey=axs[0])) for i in range(3)] #Other 3 subplots on top
axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[6:12,0:6])) #Bottom left
axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[6:12,10:16]))#Bottom right 
axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[6:9,6:10])) #Bottom middle top, reference to share x axis with bottom middle bottom
axs.append(plt.subplot(gs[9:12,6:10],sharex=axs[-1])) #Bottom middle bottom
[ax.set_xticks([]) for ax in axs]
[ax.set_yticks([]) for ax in axs]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any way to modify this so that the y-axes on the top row are shared? (as well as the x-axes for the middle two in the bottom row)

Comment: They already are. see `sharey` and `sharex` arguments in my code as well as my comments of the code